# How to know m-file location from within it?

Tags: packages, files-and-directories

I get get notebook location with [`NotebookDirectory\[\]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookDirectory.html)

How to get m-file location from within it?

Comment: `FileNames["*.m",  NotebookDirectory[]]`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
DirectoryName[$InputFileName]
```

Comment: @Dims It is good to know that this works only if evaluated while the file is being loaded. A common mistake is to define `packDir[] := DirectoryName[$InputFileName]` in the package, then try to use `packDir[]` after the package has already loaded. Instead, do `$packDir = DirectoryName[$InputFileName]; packDir[] := $packDir` in the package.